# Insert | every 2 characters when printing array

Tags: java, arrays

My question is, I have an int array I am trying to print in a certain way. I have an int array with 21 ints. Currently when I print the array I get

```
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, I am wanting it to look like this when I print

```
|10, 10| 10, 10| 10, 10| 10, 10| 10, 10| 10, 10| 0, 0| 0, 0| 0, 0| 0, 0| 0
```

I tried a for loop like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < game.getRolls().length; i += 2) {
    String sep = "|"
    System.out.print(sep);
    System.out.print(game.getRolls()[i]);
}
```

But all that does is replace every other number with |. Is there a way to change just the commas?
Thank you!

Comment: If only there was a built-in way to know if a number is even or uneven :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < game.getRolls().length; i ++)
{
    String sep = "|";
    if(i%2 == 0){
       System.out.print(sep);
    }
    else{
       System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.print(game.getRolls()[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save the array as a local variable. Next, iterate and print pairs (while there are at least two elements, I would use formatted io). Then check if there is an element remaining after the loop, if so print it. Like,

```
int[] rolls = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int i = 0;
for (; i < rolls.length - 1; i += 2) {
    System.out.printf("| %d, %d ", rolls[i], rolls[i + 1]);
}
if (i < rolls.length) {
    System.out.printf("| %d", rolls[rolls.length - 1]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that combines both @user9749556 and @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn's answers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int item = array[i];

    if (i == array.length - 1) { // The last item
        System.out.print(item);
    } else {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(item + " | ");
        } else { // The index is odd
            System.out.print(item + ", "); 
        }
    }
}

System.out.println();
```

Test cases:

```
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // prints "1, 2 | 3, 4 | 5"
array = {1, 2, 4, 8}; // prints "1, 2 | 4, 8"
array = {}; // prints ""
```

[Here's a link to the full, working code.](https://repl.it/@wilsonator5000/NauticalDelectableAutotote)

Answer (score 0):

For the lolz since the answer has already been accepted.
But I think this solution is easier to read...

```
int[] rolls = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
for (int i = 0 ; i < rolls.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print(i % 2 == 0 ? "| " : ", ");
    System.out.print(rolls[i] + " ");
}
System.out.print("|");
// output : | 10 , 10 | 10 , 10 | 10 , 10 | 10 , 10 | 10 , 10 | 10 , 10 | 0 , 0 | 0 , 0 | 0 , 0 | 0 , 0 | 0 |
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/7uzwZV)**